# Where is iptables script stored on DD-WRT filesystem?

Tags: linux, iptables, router, dd-wrt

I have an **ASUS RT-N16 router** that I've flashed with the open-source **DD-WRT** firmware.  According to my `ssh` login, I'm running:

```
DD-WRT v24-sp2 mega (c) 2010 NewMedia-NET GmbH
Release: 08/07/10 (SVN revision: 14896)
```

I'd like to be able to customize the iptables rules, but before I do that, I'd like to see the output of the built-in rules that get configured when manipulating the browser/GUI interface settings.  I am aware of the firewall script tab in the browser interface for entering custom firewall rules, but I can't find someplace to see the output.

**On a full-blown Linux system, the iptables rules would be stored somewhere like `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.  Where would I find these on a DD-WRT filesystem?**  I can do

```
iptables -L -vn --line-numbers
```

and *see* them output, but what I'm looking for is more of what the `iptables-save` command might output... so that I can incorporate the appropriate rules into my custom script.

I understand that this build does not have an `iptables-save` command.  I don't necessarily want the command itself, just output that it generates.  If there was something like `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, I wouldn't care about having `iptables-save`.  I've seen that there may be different builds of DD-WRT that give something like `iptables-save`, but I'm not at the point where I'm ready or willing to flash the router again.  Maybe as a last resort.

**EDIT:**
The *usual* Linux locations for startup scripts and the like, (e.g., `/etc/init.d`, `/etc/rc`, ...) do not seem to have anything useful (at least in the build of DD-WRT that I have installed).  For example, taking a look in `/etc/init.d`:

```
[/etc/init.d]# ll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           84 Aug  7  2010 rcS
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           10 Aug  7  2010 S01dummy
[/etc/init.d]# cat rcS
#!/bin/sh
for i in /etc/init.d/S*; do
  $i start 2>&1
done | logger -s -p 6 -t '' &
[/etc/init.d]# cat S01dummy
#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: Hmmm ... I withdrew my answer.  Is there an rc.local?  What does a **grep -ril iptables /etc/. ** yield?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Looking in**

```
/tmp/.ipt
/tmp/.rc_firewall
```

**gives exactly what I was looking for: the iptables rules as they would normally be in a file like `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.**

I had earlier found [this](http://dereenigne.org/linux/devmem-grep):

```
dd if=/dev/mem | strings | grep -i iptables
```

...and fortunately, it works on the pared-down DD-WRT filesystem.  It didn't give precisely what I was looking for, but it output quite a bit of info I hadn't been able to pinpoint any other way (or at least not with a single command).

Still have to determine which things are actually in effect by comparing with the output of

```
iptables -L -vn --line-numbers
iptables -L -vn -t nat --line-numbers
iptables -L -vn -t mangle --line-numbers
```

I also discovered that the `grep` command actually *does* work *[my apologies for initially stating that it didn't-- I would've sworn it didn't work the last times I had tried.  Mea maxima culpa.]*  Using `grep`, I found that the

```
/lib/services.so
```

also has a wealth of `iptables` configuration in it.

Comment: I know this is an old thread. I found some rules with `cat /tmp/.ipt` whil `telnet`ing into my DD-WRT router. Is this where the rules are loaded from on startup?

Answer (score 5):

There are many *WRT distribution variants, and different devices are set up in different ways, so I'm not sure whether this applies to your configuration, but it probably does.

The basic *WRT configuration has a read-only root filesystem, so it cannot save customizations in the filesystem. Instead, the [startup](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Startup_Scripts) loads various (variant-dependent) settings from [NVRAM](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Hardware#NVRAM), which is organized as a simple list of key-value pairs. The firewall rules are stored in variant-dependent [NVRAM entries](http://muchtall.com/2006/11/03/5/). Look for one whose name contains `firewall` or whose value contains `iptables`, or some such.

Run `ssh ROUTER_HOSTNAME nvram export --dump >nvram.txt` to explore your router's NVRAM content at your leasure.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the exact command you gave, but got no output.  After a little more Googling, I think the nvram command for this variant is `nvram show`.  Replacing `export --dump` with `show` gives a pretty rich output of stuff.  Unfortunately, it doesn't have the built-in SPI firewall rules in there anywhere.  The closest I seem to see is `rc_firewall`, which contains the custom rules that I can supply via the browser interface.  This is a start, though.  I suppose the stock/default iptables rules are generated by script more-or-less 'on-the-fly' at boot-up based on other values?  Maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I tried to create a symblink from `iptables` to `iptables-save` which was advised on their wiki page [DD-WRT_V24_.26_iptables-save](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Firewall_Builder#DD-WRT_V24_.26_iptables-save), but it did not work for me.

To solve this I made a shell file showing the contents of `/tmp/.ipt`.

**/jffs/bin/iptables-save**:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /tmp/.ipt
```

*NOTE: The wiki page ([DD-WRT_V24_.26_iptables-save](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Firewall_Builder#DD-WRT_V24_.26_iptables-save)) is about "Firewall Builder" - I haven't tested this solution with "Firewall Builder".*